# Calibrating Hull-White model using historical data

Tags: interest-rates, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

I'm in search of a way to calibrate a very simple Hull-White model with a constant volatility and a constant mean-reversion speed, purely based on historical zero rates.

$$dr(t) = (\theta(t) - \alpha r(t))dt + \sigma dW(t)$$

My intuition tells me that I can use the relationship between historical 1Y zero rate- and 10Y zero rate volatilities to find an implied mean reversion for the process. With this I can find the sigma which produces a variance on the 1Y return equal to the historical volatility of the 1Y zero rate. (If this works like I hope then this choice of sigma should satisfy the same condition for the 10Y zero rate).

I believe I'm looking for sigma and alpha satisfying the following relationship:
$$Var[e^{\int_0^Tr(t)dt}] = Var[e^{z(0,T)T}]$$

For T=1 and T=10, where z(0,T) are the historical zero rates. The right hand side can easily be found in the historical data, so what I need is a way of expressing the left hand side in terms of sigma, alpha, theta, and T. Taking log of both sides I'm essentially looking for an expression for:

$$Var[\int_0^Tr(t)dt].$$

Does this approach make sense to begin with? And if so, does anyone know how to proceed with such a calibration?

Thanks in advance!